# Curl command is not freeing up server resources GoLang

Tags: go, curl

I am running a GO program in which I need to run a curl command to call some other url. After initiating curl command I dont need to wait for it to complete. Due to this, It is not freeing server resources and hence I need to restart the server every morning.

Here is the code:

```
var cmd *exec.Cmd
url := "https://www.google.com/"
cmd = exec.Command("curl", "-H", "Connection: close", "--no-keepalive", "--http2", url)
var out bytes.Buffer
var stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
err := cmd.Start()
return err
```

From the above code, as you can see I only `start` the command but didn't wait for it to complete because I don't need to delay the program due to curl command.

**Other Tries:**

I have tried using `Wait()` along with `Start()` and `Run()` functions but all of these resulted in delay.

**UPDATED:**

I am running `ps -faux` command. its displaying following:

```
root     1109561  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    May26   0:00  \_ [curl] <defunct>
root     1109729  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    May26   0:00  \_ [curl] <defunct>
root     1157006  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    May26   0:00  \_ [curl] <defunct>
```

When I restart the server, then no such log found. So I guess curl is being an process in the history even after completing its job.

So is there a way to fulfill the requirement with freeing up resources ?

Comment: What is not being freed? How are you measuring that?

Comment: What do you mean by not freeing up? How do you know that?

Comment: @BurakSerdar I have updated the question with some more details.

Comment: @Amandeepkaur did you read the output of `curl`?

Comment: @leafbebop No, I am not reading the output of curl. I am only starting the command. I expect it to be completed in the background and release the resource.

Comment: Curl is a zombie process because nobody read the exit status. Wait for it to complete in a separate goroutine.

Comment: And if you don't need the output, set `cmd.Stdout` and `cmd.Stderr` to `io.Discard` would be a good idea.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I dont want to wait even with goroutine as I cant add any delay in main program. Is there a way to do this without wait ?

Comment: There would be no delay in the main goroutine if you simply create another goroutine and wait there. You have to wait for the process unless you want zombies.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Ok I will try this one. But what if I pass timeout option in curl command? Will the resources be released after the specified timeout ? And if curl request took a little longer will it be interrupted in the middle ?

Comment: No. The process stays a zombie until one of its parents wait for it. That's basic OS. It is not a huge resource, but it will be there until a process waits. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

replace `err := cmd.Start()` with `cmd.Start(); err := cmd.wait();`

> I have tried using Wait() along with Start() and Run() functions but all of these resulted in delay.

if you don't want to wait, run it in a dedicated thread (or goroutine as its called in Go), and have the thread wait while your main thread doesn't.